# Mean value theorem, Wierstrass theorems

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have a question that is related to these theorems I tried to tackle but got stuck
Please let me know if it is the proper way to go ?

The question is:
 Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
  be a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)$

Prove that exists $c\in\left[0,1\right]$
  such that $f(c)=f(c+\frac{1}{2})$

My try to solve

Set $$\left||f|\right|=max\left\{ f(x)|x\in\left[0,1\right]\right\} $$

Due to the second theorem of wierstrass :

$\forall x\in\left[0,1\right]$     $f(x)\leq\left||f|\right|$

$$\begin{aligned}\mbox{Also note that      } & c\in\left[0,1\right]\\
\rightarrow & 0\leq c\leq1\\
\iff & \frac{1}{2}\leq c+\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{3}{2}
\end{aligned}$$

However $\frac{3}{2}>1$
  ,the func is undefined there. we have to use the following statement:$\frac{1}{2}\leq c+\frac{1}{2}\leq1$
  and $0\leq c\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Therefiore we got 2 subdomains $D_{1},D_{2}$

$$\begin{aligned}D_{1}=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
\begin{aligned}D_{2}=\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\enskip\enskip
  and 2 'sub-images' \enskip\begin{aligned}I_{1}=\left\{ f(x)|x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\right\} \\
I_{2}=\left\{ f(x)|x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right\} 
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore using the second theorem of wierstrass we again deduce that

$$\begin{aligned}\forall i_{1}\in I_{1}\enskip i_{1}\leq\left||f|\right|\rightarrow\exists k_{1}\in D_{1}\enskip:f(k_{1})=\left||f|\right|\\
\forall i_{2}\in I_{2}\enskip i_{2}\leq\left||f|\right|\rightarrow\exists k_{2}\in D_{2}\enskip:f(k_{2})=\left||f|\right|
\end{aligned}$$

I feel that I need to prove that $k_2 = k_1+0.5$ and I'm done however I don't understand how to do it

Please let me know how to proceed :)

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler than that. Consider
$$
g(x)=f\Bigl(x+\frac12\Bigr)-f(x),\quad x\in[0,1/2],
$$
and observe that $g(0)+g(1/2)=0$.

Comment: Nice. I was doing a more elaborate construction with maxima and minima, ultimately aiming for an intermediate value theorem application, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: @Julián Could you please explain me 2 things-                                                     1. How did you reach your solution. 2.is my solution any good ?                       Also I was able to finish it \begin{aligned}0\leq k_{1}\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq k_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\leq1\\
\rightarrow k_{1}+\frac{1}{2}=k_{2}
\end{aligned}$$
  Now set $k_{1}=c$
  and get$ f(c)=\left||f|\right|=f(c+\frac{1}{2})$
  as needed.

Comment: What you are asked to prove is that $f(c+1/2)-f(c)=0$ for some $c$, so it was natural to consider the function $g$. I must tell that I do not understand your solution. First of all, the maximum and minimum of $f$ are attained, but if $f<0$, then $f(x)\ne\|f\|$ for all $x$. Second, even if $|\|f\|$ is attained, it may happen only in one of the intervals $D_i$. Third, even if $k_1$ and $k_2$ exist, there is no reason to expect that they differ in $1/2$.

Comment: Julian I appreciate your kind assistance sir !!!!!

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Apperantly I still have trouble understanding this :( is it possible to elaborate ? How is it that defining a $g$ function satisfies what I need for $f$ ?

Comment: It is enough to find $c$ such that $g(c)=0$. If $g(0)=g(1/2)=0$ then you can take $c=0$ or $c=1/2$.  If not, $g(0)$ and $g(1/2)$ have different signs. And of course $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre but according to what shown $g(0)+g(1/2)=0$ which means that $g(0)=-g(1/2)$ Does it mean that from this I can use the mean value theorem and say that there exists some $c\in [0,1/2]$ such that $g(c)=0$ ?

Comment: If two numbers add up two $0$, one must be negative and the other positive.